# Visual Studio Code unit tests with Mono on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mono, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run some unit tests on a .NET project (not .NET Core). Visual Studio Code is able to recognize the project, intellisense works and it even offers the links to run and debug unit tests:

[image: visual studio code in action]

The problem is that clicking the unit test does not work. It gives the following error:

> Build FAILED.
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1111,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

My guess is that it's trying to use the .NET Core MSBuild, but this is not a .NET Core project.

If I use mono's msbuild from the command line, the project builds. I'm also able to run the unit tests from the command line using NUnit's runner (from the NuGet package).

Do you know if it is possible to configure Visual Studio Code, on a Mac, so that it can run unit tests on a .NET project?

Comment: Hi Nikolaos. I faced this issue recently, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Wahid, no I hadn't at that time and I'm not using this currently. I hope you'll find some solution.